# Why Bool when summing with for-loop in Python/Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm trying to add constraints to my gurobi model (called DICP). The constraints shall make sure that the hole energy intake while using a route consisting of different links is bigger as or equal to the energy consumption (ec[r]). r are keys for the routes, l keys for the links, v keys for nodes. When compiling I get the following error:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
I think Python is trying to sum up one of the for-conditions containing a bool operation, but why? What can I do to sum up X[l, v]*ei[l] for all links in L_r and L_v for every node?

```
for route[r] in R:
A = sum(sum(X[l, v]*ei[l] for link[l] in L_r[r] and link[l] in L_v[v]) for node[v] in P)
dicp.addConstrs((A >= ec[r]), "2")
```

Thanks!

Comment: `for link[l] in L_r[r] and link[l] in L_v[v]` What do you think the `and` produces?

Comment: I think this should be the second condition for summing up the terms. So the term should be summed up only if link[l] is in both, L_r[r] and L_v[v]. But is this wrong?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `link[l]` means. It doesn't look valid python. A for loop should be `for e in s` where you do something for each element `e` in sequence `s`. You look like you'r treating `for` like it means `if`, which it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it should be: `sum(X[l, v]*ei[l] for node[v] in P if link[l] in L_r[r] and link[l] in L_v[v])`

Comment: But your `route[r]`, `node[v]` and `link[l]` syntax just looks wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it works! The syntax may look a bit unusual but it's quite right, I think. route[r], etc. are all elements of the list of routes, r are the keys to this routes in a multidict.